# Spring Batch 'beanName' must not be empty

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

In my simple `Spring Batch` application, I get the error `'beanName' must not be empty`.
I don't know, what is missing in spring configuration.

spring-beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:faces="http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces"
    xmlns:int-security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/security"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/security/spring-integration-security-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces/spring-faces-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>    
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.java.batch"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- stored job-meta in memory -->
    <bean id="jobRepository"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

    <bean id="jobLauncher"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="report" class="com.java.batch.Report" scope="prototype" />

    <bean id="customWriter" class="com.java.batch.CustomWriter" />

    <batch:job id="reportJob">
        <batch:step id="step1">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="cvsFileItemReader" writer="customWriter"
                    commit-interval="10">
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>

    <bean id="cvsFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">

        <!-- Read a csv file -->
        <property name="resource" value="classpath:report.csv" />

        <property name="lineMapper">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
                <property name="lineTokenizer">
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                        <property name="names" value="id,impressions" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                        <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="report" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="runScheduler" class="com.java.batch.RunScheduler" />

    <!-- Run every 5 seconds -->
    <task:scheduled-tasks>
        <!-- <task:scheduled ref="runScheduler" method="run" fixed-delay="5000" 
            /> -->
        <task:scheduled ref="runScheduler" method="run"
            cron="*/5 * * * * *" />
    </task:scheduled-tasks>
</beans>
```

project structure

[image]

error

```
Dec 17, 2013 2:00:32 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@145d068: startup date [Tue Dec 17 14:00:32 MMT 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Dec 17, 2013 2:00:32 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-beans.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [spring-beans.x
ml]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'beanName' must not be empty
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.java.batch.Test.main(Test.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'beanName' must not be empty
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.RuntimeBeanReference.<init>(RuntimeBeanReference.java:58)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.RuntimeBeanReference.<init>(RuntimeBeanReference.java:46)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.AbstractStepParser.setUpBeanDefinitionForTaskletStep(AbstractStepParser.java:155)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.AbstractStepParser.parseTasklet(AbstractStepParser.java:133)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.AbstractStepParser.parseStep(AbstractStepParser.java:85)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.InlineStepParser.parse(InlineStepParser.java:59)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.FlowParser.doParse(FlowParser.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.parseInternal(AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:59)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.JobParser.doParse(JobParser.java:95)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.parseInternal(AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:59)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1438)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Could you please post error stack trace?

Comment: @R.S, I updated error stack

Comment: Take a look at this, looks like the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18661290/cant-figure-out-error-causing-beanname-must-not-be-empty-in-spring-batch-job

Comment: @Pieter, Yes, I already found that. The answer is not ok for me.

Comment: I don't think spring batch 2.0.0 is compatible with spring 3. See http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/67398-spring-batch-2-0-2-release-available . Spring 3 is only supported as of spring batch 2.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd

As you mentioned in jar list the spring batch version is 2.0.0 then the xsd should be as follows

http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.0.xsd